# NLTK Python word_tokenize

Tags: python, nltk, text-mining

I have loaded a txt file that contains 6000 lines of sentences. I have tried to `split("/n")` and `word_tokenize` the sentences, but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 52, in <module>
    short_pos_words = word_tokenize(short_pos)
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 128, in word_tokenize
    sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/__init__.py", line 95, in sent_tokenize
    return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1237, in tokenize
    return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1285, in sentences_from_text
    return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1276, in span_tokenize
    return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1316, in _realign_boundaries
    for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 313, in _pair_iter
    for el in it:
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1291, in _slices_from_text
    if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1337, in text_contains_sentbreak
    for t in self._annotate_tokens(self._tokenize_words(text)):
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 1472, in _annotate_second_pass
    for t1, t2 in _pair_iter(tokens):
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 312, in _pair_iter
    prev = next(it)
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 581, in _annotate_first_pass
    for aug_tok in tokens:
  File "/home/tuanct1997/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tokenize/punkt.py", line 546, in _tokenize_words
    for line in plaintext.split('\n'):
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is related to the encoding of file's content. Assuming that you want to decode `str` to UTF-8 `unicode`:

**Option 1 (Deprecated in Python 3):**

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

**Option 2:**
Pass the `encode` parameter to the `open` function when trying to open your text file:

```
f = open('/path/to/txt/file', 'r+', encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: I would remove the option 1. It's bad advise. In Python 2, use `import io; io.open()`.

Comment: actually, i have found the solution,i using decode('utf-8') similar to Option 2. Thank you so much